# Do you really use all those WP theme options? I don't think so

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, usability

There are quite a few days now, since I started to think about creating a WP theme framework backend. Working with wordpress for some time, I studied a lot of themes from "wp theme clubs" and their backend. All settings sections are organised in vertical tabs, nothing more. Same thing again and again and again. I think 90% of the buyers (customers) will never use those options. Am I right or this is just in my mind ?

Should I create a theme backend using the same old/booooooring style or better try to think outside of the box and create some new, intuitive and innovative ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if 90% of your users don't want to customize the theme then you will leave 10% out that would like to customize your theme.

I suggest you implement 2 things to let your users customize things.

### theme customizer

Since 3.4 there is the theme customizer. It already works in twentyeleven and twentytwelve.
Take a look at it if you haven't it's quite easy to use for users and can be extended.

Read more:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API
- http://ottopress.com/2012/making-a-custom-control-for-the-theme-customizer/
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/digging-into-the-theme-customizer-overview/

### Actions and filters

You probably used `add_action()` and `add_filter()` before. You can add your own filters to your theme so more advanced users can modify stuff. It costs you less effort then making an option of it while keeping your theme easy to modify (for users who know how to code)

Check out some more extensive themes, they are full off [`do_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) and 
[`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters).

An example. Before you start your loop you might add an `do_action('before_content')`. Now a user can add an `add_action('before_content', 'add_breadcrumbs_callback_fnc');`. Now your theme will execute the `add_breadcrumbs_callback_fnc` function so the user can add breadcrumbs without editing you theme.

Read more:

- http://themeshaper.com/2009/05/03/filters-wordpress-child-themes/
- http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters/

Attempt to introduce a set of default hook for each themes:

- http://literalbarrage.org/blog/2012/06/29/wordpress-theme-hook-alliance/
- https://github.com/zamoose/themehookalliance

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily think the issue is mutually exclusive.

Users with simple needs might want simplicity, right up until options are needed. A broad and ambiguous answer to a open-ended question.

**Check out the wp-svbtle theme: https://github.com/gravityonmars/wp-svbtle**

He did a separate boiled down back end.

Comment: I know svbtle, but I meant backend options, not frontend style. Svbtle backend has 7-8 options.

Comment: Love it :-) Yes it does, but when installed the end-user can login to a separate minimalistic authors panel(write, edit, publish). Check it out.. You could do anything with the basic idea.